# classloading woes with Jboss & RestEasy using a separately deployed jar containing the javax.ws.rs.Application

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy

I have a simple setup with a war file containing only a web.xml that specifies the javax.ws.rs.Application class to use in the servlet.

The jar that contains the implementation for javax.ws.rs.Application is also completely trivial. Both the web.xml and the implementation are based off the examples in [jboss documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html)

However, I get different behavior when I deploy the war + jar combination in jboss AS 7.1.1 Final versus jboss 4.0.4. Upon accessing the rest api I get the following exception in the jboss logs (snippet only):

```
06:33:59,540 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/wrapper]] (MSC service thread 1-2) StandardWrapper.Throwable: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.projectgoth.provider.restapi.RestApiProvider from [Module "deployment.wrapper.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createFromInjectorFactory(ResteasyDeployment.java:271) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:259) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
```

If however, I change the scope of the jar from provided to runtime in the war's pom.xml - the error does indeed go away from jboss as 7.1.1.

For reference, I've uploaded the code use for both the war and jar to [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ali/jboss-resteasy) (where provider = implementation for the javax.ws.rs.Application, and wrapper is the war deployable)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is normal. `Per class loader policy, a child class can always see the parent class not the vice verse`. When you put the jar scope as runtime, the JAR is loaded in the classpath up in the stream than the WAR application and hence it's visible to the WAR classes.

Comment: I kind of understand why the behavior is as it is - but I'm super confused why it works at all in jboss 4.0.4 - which is my production setup (the current scenario is that I've managed to also break it in jboss 4.0.4 by changing the packaging of the jar) and want to understand whats the best way to go about cleaning this mess up :) Packaging the jar into the war is a bit unattractive to me, as the jar is already deployed under the jboss in question for 'other purposes'.

Comment: @Ali-AkberSaifee Given the scenario, I would prefer the put the jar in the classpath of the server. Otherwise you may package the JAR inside the WAR and update the configuration to override the classloader  policy, but I think you don't want that.